How to use/process a math formula saved in JSON - in JavaScript
I am building a conversion calculator. I would like to store the references and formulas for the calculator in JSON.
I do not know how to "process the variable as math".
JSON
var JSON = {
  "conversions": [{[
 {
   "FromType": "in3",
   "ToType": "ft3",
   "Math": "/1728",
   "Description": "divide the volume value by 1728"
 }...

With the "Math" being done something like this.
D1 = document.getElementById("data1").value;
var theAnswer = eval(D1 conversions[0].Math);

Example:
D1 = 25
theAnswer = D1 /1728
theAnswer = 0.0144675

Is this possible?  Is there a better way?

There's not really enough information here in my opinion. What kind of "Math" do you need to process? Handling a few operators in simple situations is a much different problem than writing a fully functional math parser. "/1728" is simple but /(2+3^(40*5-3)) starts to get more complex. What about (2)(3) vs *2*3 etc. I think this needs some refinement. Also, point out your specific concerns. What do you mean "better"? Does your approach not work as expected?

These will all be conversion formulas... so it will always be X (A form input)  (divided by or multiplied by a Number) Nothing more complex than that.
In this example I am passing "/1758"  as the "formula"
I could also pass  the number and the type (mulitply or divide) as separate json fields... But then I am assuming I would have to do an if/else on that. Thought it would be simpler to avoid that.  (So, that is what I was inferring - Would that be a better way? To Pass the math type as a json value.)
My concern is - my solution doesn't work at all.  It's not calculating.

I'd suggest putting some of that info into your question. Make it more apparent what you're trying to build, precisely. Make it more apparent what's going wrong (also, precisely, "it's not calculating" is much less useful than "it throws this error", or "it always returns 0", note the focus on what IS happening instead of what ISN'T happening). Also I'd suggest trying to use the JS snippet feature as a [mcve]

This question is similar to: Running an equation from a string. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. See also Evaluating a string as a mathematical expression in JavaScript, Math operations from string using Javascript, etc.

How would this JSON look when it has the formula for converting Fahrenheit to Celsius?

There are many better ways, but there is no way to tell which one is "best" given that there is no context to this question. The way shown, using eval works. Beyond working, what else is needed?

@trincot  - Not sure how that will work in this format. (I haven't gotten to that - it is up next.) In my current setup,  each conversion type is getting  its own page & json. So I would/could make that custom.

Can you explain why it needs to be JSON (i.e. the text format)? It it just has to be a JavaScript object, then you can just give the conversion object a property that is a conversion function.

It doesn't need to be json - just an easy wat to loop over possibilities. I got the eval() to work. (It was producing error SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' - which was hanging me up. For TEMP conversions I did this:
Json: {
"FromType": "F",
"ToType": "C",
"MathType": "std",
"Factor": "- 32) * 5/9",
"Description": "(1°F - 32) * 5/9"}
Note the "-32)" in the beginning of Factor: I needed to Normalize the formula so it wouldn't break in other conv. So I have to add a (
D1 = document.getElementById("data1").value;
D1A = ( + ${D1};
var theAnswer = eval( ${D1A} ${Factor});

I had previously looked at math.js. But, this is the way I use:
]
A Json Example:
const JSON = {
    "conversions": [
        {
            "FromType": "atm",
            "ToType": "psi",
            "MathType": "multiply",
            "Factor": 14.696,
            "Description": "multiply the pressure value by 14.696"
        },
        {
            "FromType": "atm",
            "ToType": "mmHg",
            "MathType": "multiply",
            "Factor": 760,
            "Description": "multiply the pressure value by 760"
        },//other fields
    ]
}

Then I loop the Json to find the FromType and ToType based on what the user selected in a select element:
function calcFormula() {
    convFrom = document.getElementById("ConvertA").value;
    convTo = document.getElementById("ConvertB").value;
    D1 = document.getElementById("data1").value;

    let conversions = JSON.conversions;

    for (var i in conversions) {
        var FromType = conversions[i].FromType;
        var ToType = conversions[i].ToType;
        var MathType = conversions[i].MathType;
        var Factor = conversions[i].Factor;
        var Description = conversions[i].Description;

        if (FromType === convFrom && ToType === convTo) {

            if (MathType === "multiply") {
                var theAnswer = (D1 * Factor);

            } else {
                var theAnswer = (D1 / Factor);
            }
            document.getElementById("convDescripton").innerHTML = Description;
        }
    }
}

It is probably not as succinct as it could be, but it is working really well so far for conversions for mass, distance, pressure, etc...

Please indent your code properly.

looks like you are trying to achieve while using eval() can work.
I won't recommend it because of security reasons. A better approach would be to use a safer method to process.
Here is my suggestion:
use a library like

mathjs

It is simple use the 'mathjs' library in the project, here is the path
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjs@9.4.4/dist/math.min.js"></script>

Then, we can use the library to evaluate math expressions.
const math = require('mathjs');

// assume the conversion is your JSON object
const conversion = conversions[0];
const D1 = document.getElementById("data1").value;
const theAnswer = math.evaluate('{$D1} ${conversion.Math}');

console.log(theAnswer);

